# Type casting to EntityCollection<Object>

Tags: c#

I have a method taking a parameter EntityCollection

Say:

```
DisplayItems(EntityCollection<Object> items);
```

Why is it not possible to call?

```
EntityCollection<Student> students;

DisplayItems((EntityCollection<Object>) students); //type casting here
```

How can I achieve this?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs because of [Covariance and Contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx), imagine that worked as you want it to, you could then do this :

```
public void DisplayItems(EntityCollection<Object> items)
{
        //Probably not called add but you get the idea...
        items.Add(new AnyObjectILike());
        items.Add(new System.Windows.Form());
}

EntityCollection<Student> students;  
DisplayItems((EntityCollection<Object>)  students); //type casting here
```

Clearly adding instances that are not of type `Student` to the `EntityCollection<Student>` causes a massive problem which is one of the reasons this is not allowed, you can alter this behaviour for interfaces using the `In` and `Out` keywords.

Answer (score -2):

Similar answer can be found here:

[convert or cast a List<t> to EntityCollection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364676/convert-or-cast-a-listt-to-entitycollectiont)

You need to loop and cast each element individually, adding them to a new EntityCollection.

Another option would be to use the Cast() method, but I'm not sure that will work with an EntityCollection. It works with a List:

```
List<Object> myItems = students.Cast<Object>().ToList();
```

I'm unable to check this would work with an EntityCollection but worth a try?

Comment: No, this is not about casting `List<>` to `EntityCollection<>` - this is about contra/co-variance between `EntityCollection<object>` and `EntityCollection<Student>`.  Different kettle of fish entirely!

Comment: I understand, but the principal is the same. Typed lists cannot be easily casted from one to the other - generally it's done one element at a time.