# How to add a child entity collection to an entity on its creation using datagridview selected rows

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datagridview

Im creating a `line` object which is an entity it has a `Tags` navigation property which I also want to set. I want to get this tags collection from a datagridview bound to `Tag` objects :

```
dgvTags.DataSource = _rs.Tags.Where(x => x.TagGroup.Name == "All Reasons").OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Code with issue :

```
Line l = new Line
{
    Part = o.Part,
    Description = desc,
    Price = o.Price.Value,
    InvoiceNo = o.InvoiceNo,
    Cost = o.Cost.Value,
    Comments = txtComment.Text,
    Tags = dgvTags.SelectedRows as List<Tag> // <--- needs work here
                    };
```

The line is showing an error :

**Error 5   Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion  C:\SVN\RS\fAddLines.cs  142 15  RS**

Is there a correct way of doing this?

UPDATE:

Ive been able to acheive the desired result with the code below, but still looking for the *correct* way to do it :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvTags.SelectedRows)
{
    l.Tags.Add(r.DataBoundItem as Tag);
}
```

Comment: you can post the code you have working as an answer rather than as an update to your question. This is the more usual way of posting solutions to you own questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to David Hall he tried very hard, but in the end the code below was the simplest solution :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvTags.SelectedRows)
{
    l.Tags.Add(r.DataBoundItem as Tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where there are lots and lots of ways of solving the problem. The code I've given below may not be the best but it works for getting a list of typed objects from the `SelectedRows` collection.

```
IList<Tag> myrows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.DataBoundItem as Tag).ToList();
```

This uses Linq, and is essentially the same as your method, the Linq just tidies things up a little by removing the foreach.

---

The problem you are having in your comment is because of no implicit converstion between the `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` created by Linq and `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<T>`.

I believe that this should work:

```
Tags = new System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<RS.Tag>(
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(x => x.DataBoundItem as Tab).ToList());
```

I say believe since I've only tested with a conversion to `BindingList<T>` not with `EntityCollection<T>`.

---

And it turns out the EntityCollection has no way of assigning a whole list! From this question here: [convert or cast a List<t> to EntityCollection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364676/convert-or-cast-a-listt-to-entitycollectiont) I came up with the following code:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(x => x.DataBoundItem as Tab).ToList().ForEach(y => Tags.Add(y));
```

I'd probably at this point prefer the vanilla `ForEach` over this oneliner.

Comment: @MuhammadA I've edited with an answer to that problem - you need to create a new EntityCollection list.

Comment: Unfortunately EntityCollection does not have a constructor that takes arguments -- so that new way is not possible.

Comment: @MuhammadA really? lol, ok, yuck :) I've added a bit to the linq that still gives a single line answer, but personally with so many chained expressions I would say that the foreach becomes more readable! Going to leave the answer incase anyone wants to do the same and is using lists that take constructor arguments.

Comment: @MuhammadA just tested that new code against EntityCollection and it works. As I say, not sure I've I'd personally prefer this code over the plain foreach... but still :)

Comment: The vanilla foreach is attractive all of the sudden, thanks for making me realise my hidden talent of making readable code :P -- thanks for all ur help.

Comment: @MuhammadA No problem, was actually fun poking around at parts of the framework that I don't use so often. As I said on your post - put what you have as an answer and explain why you ended up preferring it, then mark that as the accepted answer.